# SQL Query required using CTE

Tags: sql

Can anybody help me in writing an sql query which is defined below:
I'm having two table Itemtype and Items

```
Itemtype
-------------------
ItemTypeID ItemParent TypeName
-------------------------------
1           0          XXX
2           1          YYY
3           1          ZZZ
4           0          SSS
5           4          GGG

Items
--------------------
ItemID ItemTypeID ItemCost
----------------------------------
1        1         5000
2        2        1000
3        4        250
4        3        2000
5        5        400

Output
---------------------------
ItemtypeName ItemCost
------------------------------
XXX            8000 (1000+5000+2000)
SSS            650 (250+400)
```

These are the two tables:I joined both table using itemtypeid.
Now i need to display Items with ItemParentId = 0
and
calculate the Itemcost of Items with itemtypeId and ItemparentTypeId having value same as that of ItemTypeID.

I wrote a query using CTE,but its not displaying ItemTypeName.

```
WITH it_cte AS ( select itemtypeid from ItemType WHERE
ItemType.ItemParentType IS NULL UNION ALL select i.ItemTypeid from
ItemType i  INNER JOIN it_cte icte ON icte.itemtypeid = i.itemtypeid )
select ItemParentType,SUM(Items.ItemCost) as itemcost from ItemType 
left join Items on ItemType.ItemTypeID = Items.ItemTypeID  or
ItemType.ItemParentType= Items.ItemTypeID  group by
ItemType.ItemParentType
```

Can anybody help?

Thanks
Jamuna

Comment: You statement doesn't match your example. There is no `ItemParentType` in your example and no `NULL` values. Can we assume that `ItemParentType` is `ItemParent` and that `0` should be `NULL`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following statement

- uses a `CTE` to retrieve a list of each `ItemTypeID` with its root `ItemTypeID`
- joins with `ItemType` to get the `TypeName`
- joins with `Items` to get the `ItemCost`
- groups on `TypeName` to get the sum of the `ItemCost`

**SQL Statement**

```
;WITH q AS (
  SELECT  ItemTypeID , Root = ItemTypeID
  FROM    ItemType
  WHERE   ItemParent = 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  t.ItemTypeID, q.Root
  FROM    q
          INNER JOIN ItemType t ON t.ItemParent = q.ItemTypeID
) 
SELECT  it.TypeName, SUM(i.ItemCost)
FROM    q
        INNER JOIN ItemType it ON it.ItemTypeID = q.Root
        INNER JOIN Items i ON i.ItemTypeID = q.ItemTypeID
GROUP BY
        it.TypeName
```

**Test script**

```
;WITH ItemType (ItemTypeID, ItemParent, TypeName) AS (
  SELECT 1, 0, 'XXX' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 1, 'yyy' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 1, 'ZZZ' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 0, 'SSS' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 4, 'GGG'
)
, Items (ItemID, ItemTypeID, ItemCost) AS (
  SELECT 1, 1, 5000 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 2, 1000 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 4, 250 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 3, 2000 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 5, 400
)
, q AS (
  SELECT  ItemTypeID , Root = ItemTypeID
  FROM    ItemType
  WHERE   ItemParent = 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  t.ItemTypeID, q.Root
  FROM    q
          INNER JOIN ItemType t ON t.ItemParent = q.ItemTypeID
) 
SELECT  it.TypeName, SUM(i.ItemCost)
FROM    q
        INNER JOIN ItemType it ON it.ItemTypeID = q.Root
        INNER JOIN Items i ON i.ItemTypeID = q.ItemTypeID
GROUP BY
        it.TypeName
```

Comment: Thanks Man! Very nicely explained!

Comment: I was also trying to propose an answer in the meanwhile, but I know I would have only came up with a solution but you have explained it quite well!

Comment: @SHAKIRSHABBIR - Thank you, good to know the explanation is helpfull. It takes more time to get right than the actuall statement :)